# Failed to find 'ANDROID_HOME' environment variable

Tags: android, ionic-framework, android-sdk-tools

When I type `sudo ionic build android` I get this error

```
Error: Failed to find 'ANDROID_HOME' environment variable. Try setting setting it manually.
Failed to find 'android' command in your 'PATH'. Try update your 'PATH' to include path to valid SDK directory.
```

and I have the following lines on .bashrc

```
export ANDROID_HOME=~/Android
export PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_HOME:~/Android/Sdk/tools:~/Android/Sdk/platform-tools:~/node/bin
```

and the android command work con the console.

EDIT:

This is now my .bashrc file

```
export ANDROID_HOME="~/Android/Sdk"
export PATH="$PATH:$ANDROID_HOME/tools:$ANDROID_HOME/platform-tools:~/node/bin"
```

I still fails the same way

I have to execute  `sudo ionic build android`
 or I get :

```
Error: EACCES: permission denied, open '/home/user/.config/configstore/update-notifier-cordova.json'
You don't have access to this file.
```

Answer (score 2):

If you have installed ionic globally, you should not call `sudo`. Just execute:

```
ionic build android
```

And I think your `ANDROID_HOME` should be set to `~/Android/Sdk`.
Here is my environment variable for android sdk that you may read just for reference:

```
ANDROID_HOME="~/Android/android-sdk-macosx"
PATH="${ANDROID_HOME}/tools:${ANDROID_HOME}/platform-tools:${PATH}"
export ANDROID_HOME PATH
```